# Preserve a widget in Flutter to reuse across multiple routes

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a youtube player from the *flutter_youtube_player* package which works and plays youtube videos.
However, I want the player to be singleton and have the video player in multiple routes of the app playing the same video when the respective route is visited.
The problem is the player loses it's state when moved to a different route and video starts from start again.
I have used `AutomaticKeepAliveMixin` but with no luck in this case.
I have used an alternate solution to pass the playback time state and the video resumes but with much lag and isn't giving a seemless feel.
It would be better if the widget could stay alive and I could just plug it inside any widget tree and it continues to play as it is.
Is it possible to do that in Flutter?

Comment: Consider using some state management technique like Provider, Bloc or RiverPod to manage the state of your youtube player

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that when I said I am passing the playback time.